# Can not tap anywhere after click Use button in UIImagepickercontroller ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiimagepickercontroller

I have a problem, after record video, I click on Use button to save this video to library but after save done, I can not tap on Play button or Retake button. This is my code :

```
  -(void)actionLaunchAppCamera
{
    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
    {
        UIImagePickerController * imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

        if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])  {
            imagePickerController.mediaTypes =  [NSArray arrayWithObject:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie];
            imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
            imagePickerController.showsCameraControls = YES;
            imagePickerController.allowsEditing = YES;
            imagePickerController.cameraCaptureMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureModeVideo;
            imagePickerController.delegate = self;
            imagePickerController.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceRear;

            [self presentModalViewController:imagePickerController animated:YES];
            //[imagePickerController release];
        }
    }
}
```

saving the image that was taken

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{
    ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
    NSURL *recordedVideoURL= [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];

    if ([library videoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum:recordedVideoURL]) {
        [library writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum:recordedVideoURL
                completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error){
                    [library assetForURL:assetURL resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset) {
                        NSDate* date = [asset valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyDate];
                        NSLog(@"Date Time Modify %@",date);
                        NSDateFormatter* formatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
                        [formatter setDateFormat: @"dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss"];
                        NSString* CurrentDateStamp = [formatter stringFromDate:date];

                        NSLog(@"NameVideo %@",asset.defaultRepresentation.filename);
                        NSLog(@"DateModify %@",CurrentDateStamp);
                        NSLog(@"Size: %lld", asset.defaultRepresentation.size);
                    } failureBlock:nil];

 actionSheetUpload= [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Do you want to upload this video?" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:@"Upload" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                actionSheetUpload.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleBlackOpaque;
                [actionSheetUpload showInView:[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow];
                [actionSheetUpload release];
                }
         ];
    }
   [library release];
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance

Comment: Then where is the code to play ..? You are just saving the Video, after that need to play the Video

Comment: After saving the video, I will upload this video to Server. I updated code in my question.

Comment: Then you should use the player to get it play.?

Answer (score 0):

The Code is just fine for saving the video, If you want to get it play. Then You need to use player to get it play.

For Example:

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{
    NSURL *recordedVideoURL= [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
.// Save Your Stuff
.
.

     MPMoviePlayerController *movieplayer =[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL: recordedVideoURL];    
    [[movieplayer view] setFrame: 
    [self.view bounds]];  
    [self.view addSubview: 
    [movieplayer view]];
    [movieplayer play];
}
```

Edit:
 For Uploading a Video, According to your code :
Declare the `NSURL *recordedVideoURL;`

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
    //NSLog(@"but ind %d", buttonIndex);
    if (buttonIndex == uploadBTnIndex) {
     NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:recordedVideoURL];
   //Use this NSData to upload, So what else your problem to upload using web Services ?
}
```

Comment: Thanks but i dont need to play video. I just need to upload it to server.

Comment: Then what is the problem , You are asking me to do the code for uploading after done(save).

Comment: My problem is after click on Use video, it will show Actionsheet Uploading, then I click on Cancel on Actionsheet to back UIImagePickercontroller, but the UIImagePickerController seems can not click on any button.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you not dismiss picker with `- (void)dismissViewControllerAnimated: (BOOL)flag completion: (void (^)(void))completion`